# slice data between the range of dates SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am having a miserable time in achieving a simple task. I want to slice data for every 6-months every month. I am not getting any output. My SQL skills are very bad. I searched for the solution a lot and they gave me some idea but I am not able to any output.

Below is my attempt:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(HOUR,-4,DATEADD(s, ch.dateTimeOrigination, '19700101')), 121) as CallDate 
FROM [dbo].[CallData] AS ch 
WHERE LEN(ch.callingPartyNumber) = 4 AND 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(HOUR,-4,DATEADD(s, ch.dateTimeOrigination, '19700101')), 121) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()), 110)
```

The table definitely has the data for the time period I am trying to query. So I am not sure why this is not giving me any output. I will really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: you will get more answers if you include sample data and expected outcome, not as an image but as text

Comment: Interesting, I never realized that `BETWEEN` works on varchars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your `BETWEEN` values are backwards.

EDIT: Your `CONVERT` statements in the `WHERE` clause are also different formats, so when you compare your varchars, the comparison fails. You should instead use `DATETIME`.

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(HOUR,-4,DATEADD(s, ch.dateTimeOrigination, '19700101')), 121) as CallDate 
FROM [dbo].[CallData] AS ch 
WHERE LEN(ch.callingPartyNumber) = 4 AND 
CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,DATEADD(s, ch.dateTimeOrigination, '19700101')) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: Nop, still no output.

Comment: Ok. In that case, you should provide table structure for `dbo.CallData`, sample data, and expected output in your Question post. It'll be your best chance to get meaningful help. I'll update this answer if I see anything else.

Comment: I got it where it working. You were right, `BETWEEN` was not working so I changed `WHERE` CLAUSE as `WHERE LEN(ch.callingPartyNumber) = 4 AND 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(HOUR,-4,DATEADD(s, ch.dateTimeOrigination, '19700101')), 121) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()), 121) AND 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(HOUR,-4,DATEADD(s, ch.dateTimeOrigination, '19700101')), 121) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 121) ORDER BY CallDate desc`

Comment: You can still use `BETWEEN`. The reason your comparison was failing was because you were converting datetime values to different varchar formats. You should instead compare datetime values. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Ah! Got it. Thank you for your time.